# Unexpected behavior: missing characters in the code page 936

Tags: bugs, character-encoding, unicode

**Bug persisting through 13.1.0**

---

In the `CP936.m` file which will be loaded by

```
Internal`LoadEncodingFile@"CP936";
```

there are 21674 characters, while the [definition of CP936](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP936.TXT) includes 21920 unicode characters.

e.g.

```
ToCharacterCode["\[LongDash]", "CP936"]
(* None *)
```

Seems that the characters which has lower unicode has been removed from the file. But I didn't see the same thing in the `CP949.m`:

```
ToCharacterCode["\:2015", "CP949"]
(* {161, 170} *)
```

So I think it's an unexpected behavior.

This is a fundamental component and big trouble may arise. Some fall-back mechanism has prevented this issue from discovery.

Comment: Have you reported this to the support?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes. They said that it will be fixed in future.

Comment: So they confirmed it is a bug?.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov The customer service said that. Not sure about how developers think of this.

Comment: This is as close to 'it is a bug' as you can get from support :)

Answer (score 7):

This can be fixed by substituting the encoding file or creating a new one.

---

Import the definition of cp936:

```
src = Import@"http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP936.TXT";
lines = Select[StringTake[#,1]=!="#"&]@OperatorApplied[StringSplit]["\n"]@src;
chars = OperatorApplied[StringSplit]["\t"]@lines;
unichars = Select[#[[2]]=!="      "&]@chars;
unicodes = Map[FromDigits[StringDrop[#,2],16]&]@*Most/@unichars;
```

By the way, look at the difference of lengths:

```
Length@chars
Length@unichars
Internal`LoadEncodingFile["CP936"][[2]] //Length
```

Export it to a new file:

```
encoding = {"CP936M", Select[unicodes, Apply[UnsameQ]]}
Export[FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles",
                     "CharacterEncodings","CP936M.m"}, encoding]
```

Test it:

```
ToCharacterCode["\[LongDash]", "CP936M"]
(* {161, 170} *)
```